# Why am I getting an Uncaught ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined

Tags: javascript, socket.io, plotly

I am getting an `Uncaught ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined` error when my page loads. The following code is beneath my div element where the plot is rendered, but on the line `Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', dataPlot, layout);` within the `socket.on` listener is where this error is being thrown.

```
var dataPlot = [{
    x: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    y: [0, 0, 0, 0],
    type: 'bar'
}];

var layout = {
    autosize: false,
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    margin: {
        l: 50,
        r: 50,
        b: 100,
        t: 100,
        pad: 4
    }
};

// Listener, whenever the server emits 'updatechat', this updates the chat body
socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
    $('#conversation').append('<b>'+username + ':</b> ' + data + '<br>');
    if (data ==='a'){
        dataPlot[0]['y'][0]++;
    } else if (data === 'b'){
        dataPlot[0]['y'][1]++;
    } else if (data === 'c'){
        dataPlot[0]['y'][2]++;
    } else if (data === 'd'){
        dataPlot[0]['y'][3]++;
    }
    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', dataPlot, layout);
});

$("#clearplot").click(function() {
    var dataPlot = [{
    x: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    y: [0, 0, 0, 0],
    type: 'bar'
    }]
    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', dataPlot, layout);
});
```

I have included `<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>` in the head of my HTML5 document, and the `Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', dataPlot, layout);` within my `clearplot` function is working just fine. Why is there an error only in the `updatechat` listener?

**EDIT**
I figured out the issue. The issue was that this code is embedded in an Angular app, so I just had to include the `<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>` within the head of the template HTML file, not the local HTML file.

Comment: That can only mean that the event handler is executed before plotly is fully loaded.

Comment: Ah, so how might I make sure plotly gets fully loaded before it reaches my listener? I thought having `<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>` in the head was loaded first...

Comment: Yep............

Comment: put this code into $(function() {}); and if it works, then it's a library loading issue like first commenter said

Comment: Still doesn't make a difference... I have no idea what the issue could be now.

Comment: The issue was that I was using angular and a templating engine, so I included the `<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>` in the head of the template HTML file.

Comment: Hi @RetroGamer, I just had this issue. Can you explain why it has to move somewhere else?

Comment: your solution is too slow since every time the page wants to reload itself, the whole js file should get downloaded again! But it seems the only working option.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you forgot to include `Plotly` script reference to your code.
Try to add:
`<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>`
In the `<head>` section of your HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I have used the wrong script. It took me some minutes and patience to found out.

Just to maybe help somebody else:

I was using:

```
src="plotly-2.12.1.min.js"
```

Should use:

```
src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.12.1.min.js"
```

**For new ones to Angular**: it is the same trick of Boostrap, you either import from a link or download the whole package, and place it locally on Assets. I wanted to use the package without downloading, but calling locally, generally in Assets of Angular app folder.

[Documentation here](https://plotly.com/javascript/getting-started/)